# Finding the last reference in a collection

Tags: java, collections

I have  a collection of objects. Each object contains a string called "Status". I want to check the collection for the last reference of the status being either "Paid" or "NotPaid".

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: telling us which collection you're using is non-trivial, since answers will be collection-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that "colleciton" by itself does not dictate sequence or ordering, hence there is no concept of last element in a collection.

For a sequenced/ordered version of collection you might have to use List/Queue, in which case getting the last element is very trivial.

Comment: +1: PriorityQueue does not have an ordered Iterator which might make it unsuitable.  Best to stick with Lists.

Comment: How would this be possible with Lists?

Comment: I think he's looking for last 'reference' to a particular String value, which is not necessarily the last item in List.

Comment: Use a ListIterator starting at the end of the list, and call hasPrevious() and previous() in a loop until you find an element having the appropriate status. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28int%29